# Securely store Realm Encrypted Key for existing .realm file

Tags: android, realm

There is a pre-existing database within the app which is encrypted using a key. To access the database realm key has to be provided within the app. Even if I use Android key store I still have to put static key somewhere within the code. How to securely store that key.

Comment: Do you have a backend server available?

Comment: Its a pity, as the safest option is to store the key remotely and to access it via secure web services or a RESTful service.

Comment: Check out this article: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2268753&seqNum=4 for options.

Comment: Here you can see how to generate a key and keep it securely in the keystore, and unlock it using a security pattern or a fingerprint: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/feature/example/store_password/examples/StoreEncryptionPassword/src/main/java/realm/io/storeencryptionpassword/Store.java

Comment: @CliveSeebregts that is specific to SQLite I am using realm

Comment: @Emanuelez I already have an encrypted database. I want to ship it with my app. I have to put a key somewhere in my app to open that database.

Comment: It's using SQLCipher as an example, as you also need a key to open an SQLCipher database. You could follow the same strategy as outlined in the article obviously excluding the SQLCipher part.

Comment: Then the link posted by @CliveSeebregts is your best option. The same concepts can be applied to Realm